Wikipedia: Convex combination vs weighted average
Wikipedia: Convex combination

a convex combination is a linear combination of points (which can be vectors, scalars, or more generally points in an affine space) where all coefficients are non-negative and sum to 1. In other words, the operation is equivalent to a standard weighted average, but whose weights are expressed as a percent of the total weight, instead of as a fraction of the count of the weights as in a standard weighted average.

What does this mean exactly please? I don't get this percent vs fraction and then how ultimately a convex combination is different from a weighted average.
Guess: There's this
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Convex_combination_example

Since only the relative weights are relevant, any weighted mean can be expressed using coefficients that sum to one. Such a linear combination is called a convex combination.

I guess it looks like the weights being discussed are the ones without the denominator sum?
Idk is this a textbook/convention issue? Weights afaik always sum to 1 (well except I think in operations research / linear programming or something iirc...). Why  in a weighted average  $\frac{w_1x_1+w_2x_2}{w_1+w_2}$ would you consider the weights as the $(w_1,w_2)$ as not the $(\frac{w_1}{w_1+w_2},\frac{w_2}{w_1+w_2})$?

Fix a vector space $X$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in X$.
Imagine that we have individual weights $\theta_i$ and a total weight $\sum_{j=1}^n \theta_j$. The weights tell of the "relative importance", and the ratios $$\frac{\theta_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n \theta_h}$$ give the "absolute importance".
The only difference between a convex combination and a weighted average in this context is that for a convex combination, we divide by the total weight first to get $$w_i=\frac{\theta_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n \theta_j},$$ and then give you the $w_i$ (without you ever having to see the $\theta_i$), whereas in the weighted average, we give you the $\theta_i$ and when we apply these as coefficients, we divide by the total weight to get $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\theta_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n \theta_j}x_i=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n \theta_j x_j}{\sum_{j=1}^n \theta_j}.$$
The resulting vector is the same. So the only difference really is whether the weights presented already have the division done (convex combination) or not (weighted average).

ok thanks .... ah ok wait I thought of something... the relevance of weights where you don't divide is kinda like ... oh idk like in linear algebra - any vector in $\mathbb R^2$ where you don't normalise it like not everything has to be normalised? so here we can give a name '(non-normal) weights' to the relevant information (20,30) are like students in a classroom and then we can't just say divide and say the normalised (0.4,0.6) is the weight because like then (20,30) doesn't mean anything ... or something? idk lol

You could take arbitrary scalars, say $(c_j){j=1}^n$, and take a linear combination $$\sum{j=1}^n c_jx_j,$$ without normalizing. These could be complex/negative. This would be analogous to an integral with respect to a complex/signed measure, and the examples in your original question would then play the role of expectations (integrals wrt probability measures). So you are exactly right that the analogy can be taken this far. But I'm not too familiar with the usefulness of the analogy once it has been taken this far.

I say "analogy", but convex combinations are not analogous to expectations. They are expectations. If $(w_i){i=1}^n$ are positive numbers summing to $1$ and $X$ is a vector space, we define a random vector $Y$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Y=x_i)=w_i$, and $$\mathbb{E}(Y)=\sum{i=1}^n w_ix_i.$$  Here we want the $x_i$ to be distinct
Dropping the assumption that the scalars are non-negative and sum to $1$, we have a complex/signed measure and a random variable whose expectation  is the linear combination.

Weights do not necessarily have to sum to $1$ in a weighted average, but they do in a convex combination.  Here is an example of a weighted average with non-negative weights that do not sum to 1.
Suppose you get charged a 1% fee for transferring money on Monday, and a 2% fee for transferring money on Tuesday.  It sounds like you pay 1.5% on average, but what if you transfer 100 USD on Monday and only 50 USD on Tuesday?
Now your total average transfer fee is (100 USD x 1% + 50 USD x 1.5%) / 2 transfers, which is 1.75 USD /2 = 0.875 USD per transfer.  This is a weighted average, but the weights were 1% and 1.5% (or 0.01 and 0.015).  They did not sum to 1.  Notice also that I divided by 2, which is the "count of the weights" that the Wikipedia article alluded to.
Sure, we could have used normalised weights that did sum to 1 (0.01/0.025 + 0.015/0.025 = 1), but that feels a bit unnatural.
What matters here is that the convex combination must sum to $1$ so the weighted average I just described was not a convex combination.
Also, a weighted average can have negative weights.  This is another thing that distinguishes it from a convex combination.
There is nothing profound here.  It's just that the definition of a convex combination is more restricted than the definition of a weighted average.
It is true that a weighted average typically features non-negative weights which sum to 1 (and so is a convex combination), but it is certainly not always the case.  I think it is better to think of a weighted average as "layman speak", which you can contrast with the various types of combinations and means; these are precisely defined.
So a weighted average (which can have negative weights and sum to anything) covers more cases than an affine combination (which can have negative weights but must sum to 1), which covers more cases than a convex combination (which cannot have negative weights and must sum to 1).
A weighted average is, in the most general sense, a linear combination, but it is often a convex combination.
